# JOGL Loading textures individually and using multiple at once

Tags: java, opengl, dynamic, textures, lwjgl

Alright, I couldn't find a good name for this, so I will explain in a bit further detail.

I am making a game using LWJGL and I have gotten some basic rendering done, but now I want to do something a bit more advanced.

Here is the situation:

I have a mesh (positions, normals, texture coords, indices) I generate which can currently support 1 texture, this would be great if I had a single image containing all of the textures, but sadly that isn't the case. I have a individual image for each texture which needs to be loaded individually.

Now, I see a way how I could do this, but it doesn't seem practical or like a good usage of memory.
-Load all the textures into one image and save where each one is in that image for usage with the texture coords.

The textures should **NOT** blend together, hard coding anything is not an option as I wish to allow modding to be easy to implement, and anywhere from 1 (best case scenario) to 65,536+ textures (worst case scenario) are able to be used in the same "mesh".

Comment: The reason I was wishing not to use a texture atlas is because I have no idea what content will be loaded. Since I am wanting to mod this game, I would have to generate it at run time, while also storing the location in that atlas. I would also have to enforce a max texture size, which isn't exactly what I want. @httpdigest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am simply going to use a Texture Atlas as doing anything else seems impractical. Thanks @httpdigest for the suggestion.